# HTML form still submit when I return false from onsubmit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

here is html form :

```
 <form id="form1" name="form1" action="toSQL.php" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8"   onsubmit="return submitTest();">
<p><input type="text" name="Cliname" id="textfield" maxlength = "10" /></p>
<p><textarea name="message" id="message" maxlength = "20" ></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="btn"/>
</form>
```

here is js:

```
<script type="text/javascript" > 
function submitTest() { 
   if ( form1.textfield.value == "" ) {
       alert( "enter your name!!" ) ;
       form1.name.focus();
       return false ;
   } 

   if (form1.message.value == "" ) {
       alert( "type the content!!" ) ;
       form1.message.focus();
      return false ;
   } 
} 
</script>
```

alert is showed but it still send the form to sql.
i have no idea :(

Comment: I *think* that `form1.textfield.value` should be `form1.Cliname.value`

Comment: i tried, it still send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form submitted because there's error on your code. Browser can't find form child with id `name` on `form1.name.focus();`. Change it to `form1.textfield.focus();`.

Answer (score 0):

In normal (non-jQuery) event handlers, return false does not stop the event from bubbling up.

Please see [event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can as well use `required` for HTML5

```
<input type="text" required name="Cliname" id="textfield" maxlength = "10" />
```